How to position an image inside a div, on the right side, and under another div?
This is the design I want to achieve: link.

I have tried to make two separate Div's and one to be placed above another, but it doesn't work.
I honestly thought of placing the image as a background to the main Div, but that opens new problems. But if this is the right approach I'll go with this.
I honestly don't know how to find a solution to this problem.
<div class="parent">
   <div class="above">
     <div>Square1</div>
     <div>Square2</div>
     <div>Square3</div>
   </div>
   <div class="under"><img src="....."></div>
</div>



  .parent {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    max-width: 750px;
    background-color: white;
  }


.under {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    align-items: right;
    justify-content: right;
}

.under img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    align-self: right;
}

.above {
    position: absolute;
}


For the image, you can position it absolute with right:0 and top:-50px all in relation to a relative .parent, of course. Give it a z-index lower than the other squares and it will appear below them.
Here is a quick sketch.


.parent {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.above {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-around
}

.above>div {
  background: red;
}

.under {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: -50px;
  bottom: -50px;
  z-index: -1;
}
<div class="parent">
  <div class="above">
    <div>Square1</div>
    <div>Square2</div>
    <div>Square3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="under"><img src="https://picsum.photos/100/200"></div>
</div>




Thank you for the answer. 15 minutes after I posted the question I solved it using a 4th div and placing the image as a background in that one. The solution you gave seems to be ok. I'll mark it as Solution.

Try updating html & css like this, choose width and height for parent based on your needs
**HTML**

<div class="parent">
    <div class="under"><img src="./assets/landscape-img.jpg" class="img- 
        fluid"></div>
      <div class="square">Square1</div>
      <div class="square">Square2</div>
      <div class="square">Square3</div>
 </div>

CSS
.parent {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
    max-width: 750px;
    height: 15rem;
    background-color: white;
 }


 .under {
     overflow: hidden;
     display: flex;
     align-items: right;
    justify-content: right;
    height: 100%;
  }   

 .under img {
     width: 100%;
     height: auto;
     align-self: right;
  }

  .above {
     position: absolute;
  }

  .square{
      border:1px solid black;
      height: 100% !important;
      background-clip: content-box;
      margin: 1rem;
      height: 100%;
  }
 .img-fluid{
     max-width: 100% !important;
    height: auto;
   }

